# Escape characters <%= h("") %> and how to deal with double quote in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping

This might be a simple question to answer, but I couldn't find the answer.

In Ruby on Rails, I thought the helper function would help escape special characters.

Example: " She's the one that took me "to" "

Code wise: `<%= h("She's the one that took me "to" ") %>`

However, the double quote won't allow me to display the code on the browser and gives me an error.

I thought the h() is an alias for html_escape() and they convert the following 4
characters

```
 <   >    &    "
```

into

```
&lt;   &gt;  &amp;  &quot;
```

Is there something i'm missing with using double quotes?

Any advice is appreciated Thanks,
D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your double quote around the word *to* is closing the double quote opened at the beginning of the string. Try this:

```
<%= h("She's the one that took me \"to\" ") %>
```

Or, to avoid having to backslashify the internal double quotes, you could use the [% syntax](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation) for creating the string:

```
<%= h(%[She's the one that took me "to" ]) %>
```